# Get version number from resource file

Tags: visual-c++

I have DLL library project in my Visual Studio c++. Projects includes resource file with version info. How to get FILEVERSION value to my dll c++ code? I need to create function that returns dll version string.

```
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "windows.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Lithuanian (Lithuania) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_LTH)
LANGUAGE LANG_LITHUANIAN, SUBLANG_LITHUANIAN

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""afxres.h""\r\n"
    "\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Version
//

VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION 1,0,0,3
 PRODUCTVERSION 0,0,0,0
 FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL
#ifdef _DEBUG
 FILEFLAGS 0x1L
#else
 FILEFLAGS 0x0L
#endif
 FILEOS 0x40004L
 FILETYPE 0x2L
 FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "042704b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "Comments", "undefined"
            VALUE "CompanyName", ""
            VALUE "FileDescription", ""
            VALUE "FileVersion", "1.0.0.3"
            VALUE "InternalName", "mydll.dll"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright (C) 2023"
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "mydll.dll"
            VALUE "ProductName", "mydll.dll"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", "undefined"
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x427, 1200
    END
END

#endif    // Lithuanian (Lithuania) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```